# Unable to test on iPhoneSimulator with Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning, xamarin-studio

I'm currently developping an app on Xamarin Studio with Xamarin.Forms the app works fine in android but on ios i can't even build my app ...

At first i had the "no valid ios code signing keys found in keychain" error so i did add my Apple Id on XCode has I saw on a forum and I did follow the tutorial on how to add a developer certificate i did refresh my provisioning profiles on xcode and added them all (iOS Development, iOS Distribution, Developer ID Application, etc) .

Now I have another error still on build that say "Error executing task DetectSigningIdentity: Directory '/Users/.../Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles' not found."

I don't understand since i'm just trying to execute it on the iPhoneSimulator in Debug mode and i should have the certificate iOS Developer ....

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new solution in XCode with the same bundle identifer as your xamarin project. After creating a new solution you get a new page where you can click on fix issue.

Connect your apple device and click on fix issue it will maybe solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are actually very close. Now that you have created your provisioning profiles, all you have to do is download them (or at least one) and execute them. That will automatically place the profile at the path that is reported on your error. After that you'll be good to go.